# Download file using c# where the file name is unknown and the path does not have an extension

Tags: c#, url, web, download, webclient

Basically I have a url that looks like this 
http://127.0.0.1/here
that when clicked automatically downloads a zip file. 
I've tried using webclient methods but can't seem to get it to work and keep getting errors. I've tried to make the webclient download all files in that folder but it bombs out every time and can't access the url properly.

I am trying to get a client application to download a file from the webserver.
Webclient.DownloadFile does not work and returns "unknown error". Instead of being specific and downloading the zip file, I tried to download any file that was in the directory.

Comment: If you manually open `http://127.0.0.1/here` with a web browser, what happens?

Comment: It automatically opens a download window. Like "download file/cancel"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I got it working. Turns out the webclient was throwing 401's but I didn't handle the error checking properly so I didn't pick up on it.
Adding in "usedefaultcredentials" fixed my issue.

```
        string url = "http://127.0.0.1/here";
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        client.DownloadFile(new Uri(url), @"C:\temp\test.zip");
```

Answer (score 1):

By using `GetResponseStream` you can directly write the downloaded response to a file.

```
public static void SaveUrlToFile(string uri, string filePath)
{
    var fileReq =  HttpWebRequest.Create(uri) as HttpWebRequest;

    //Create a response for this request
    var fileResp = (HttpWebResponse) fileReq.GetResponse();

    //Get the Stream returned from the response
    using (var stream = fileResp.GetResponseStream())
    {
        using (var fileStream = File.OpenWrite(filePath))
        {
            stream.CopyTo(fileStream);
        }
    }
}
```

Note that `HttpWebRequest.Create(url)` as defined [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bw00b1dc(v=vs.110).aspx) needs a URI to be passed in, so make sure you put `http` or `https` at the start. So your call would be something like `SaveUrlToFile("http://127.0.0.1/here", "output.zip")`